# almostIncreasingSequence

Tags: rust

This is assignment from codesignal:

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

```rust
fn almostIncreasingSequence(sequence: Vec<i32>) -> bool {
    if sequence.len() == 2
        || sequence.len() == 3 && (sequence[1] > sequence[0] || sequence[2] > sequence[1])
    {
        true
    } else {
        let mut no_increase = sequence[1] <= sequence[0];
        for i in 2..(sequence.len() - 1) {
            //println!("sequence[{}] {}", i, sequence[i]);
            //println!("no_increase {:?}", no_increase);
            if sequence[i] <= sequence[i - 1] {
                if no_increase
                    || sequence[i] <= sequence[i - 2] && sequence[i + 1] <= sequence[i - 1]
                    || i == (sequence.len() - 2) && sequence[i + 1] <= sequence[i]
                {
                    return false;
                }
                no_increase = true;
            } else if i == (sequence.len() - 2) && no_increase && sequence[i + 1] <= sequence[i] {
                return false;
            }
        }
        true
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_almostIncreasingSequence() {
    let samples: Vec<(Vec<i32>, bool)> = vec![
        (vec![3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3], false),
        (vec![1, 3, 2, 1], false),
        (vec![1, 2, 1, 2], false),
        (vec![0, -2, 5, 6], true),
        (vec![10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], true),
        (vec![40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30], false),
        (vec![3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 20, 15], false),
        (vec![1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], false),
    ];

    for (inputArray, expected) in samples {
        println!("\n{:?}", inputArray);
        assert_eq!(expected, almostIncreasingSequence(inputArray));
    }
}
```

Run with `cargo test test_almostIncreasingSequence`

Edit: Added check for `i == (sequence.len() - 2)` element

Edit: Added more tests as suggested which showed bug for `sequence.len() == 3`. Now fixed:

```rust
fn almostIncreasingSequence(sequence: Vec<i32>) -> bool {
    if sequence.len() < 3 {
        true
    } else if sequence.len() == 3 {
        sequence[1] > sequence[0] || sequence[2] > sequence[1] || sequence[2] > sequence[0]
    } else {
        let mut no_increase = sequence[1] <= sequence[0];
        for i in 2..(sequence.len() - 1) {
            //println!("sequence[{}] {}", i, sequence[i]);
            //println!("no_increase {:?}", no_increase);
            if sequence[i] <= sequence[i - 1] {
                if no_increase
                    || sequence[i] <= sequence[i - 2] && sequence[i + 1] <= sequence[i - 1]
                    || i == (sequence.len() - 2) && sequence[i + 1] <= sequence[i]
                {
                    return false;
                }
                no_increase = true;
            } else if i == (sequence.len() - 2) && no_increase && sequence[i + 1] <= sequence[i] {
                return false;
            }
        }
        true
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_almostIncreasingSequence() {
    let samples: Vec<(Vec<i32>, bool)> = vec![
        (vec![], true),
        (vec![1], true),
        (vec![1, 1], true),
        (vec![1, 1, 1], false),
        (vec![3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3], false),
        (vec![1, 3, 2, 1], false),
        (vec![1, 2, 1, 2], false),
        (vec![0, -2, 5, 6], true),
        (vec![10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], true),
        (vec![40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30], false),
        (vec![3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 20, 15], false),
        (vec![1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], false),
    ];

    for (inputArray, expected) in samples {
        println!("\n{:?}", inputArray);
        assert_eq!(expected, almostIncreasingSequence(inputArray));
    }
}
```

Edit: Checking for edge case moved out of loop.

```rust
fn almostIncreasingSequence(sequence: Vec<i32>) -> bool {
    if sequence.len() < 3 {
        true
    } else if sequence.len() == 3 {
        sequence[1] > sequence[0] || sequence[2] > sequence[1] || sequence[2] > sequence[0]
    } else {
        let mut no_increase = sequence[1] <= sequence[0];
        for i in 2..(sequence.len() - 1) {
            //println!("sequence[{}] {}", i, sequence[i]);
            //println!("no_increase {:?}", no_increase);
            if sequence[i] <= sequence[i - 1] {
                if no_increase
                    || sequence[i] <= sequence[i - 2] && sequence[i + 1] <= sequence[i - 1]
                {
                    return false;
                }
                no_increase = true;
            }
        }

        if no_increase && sequence[sequence.len() - 1] <= sequence[sequence.len() - 2] {
            return false;
        }
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost increasing? I'd say it's either increasing or it isn't, but I suspect the actual problem assignment would clarify this. Can you post more about what the code is supposed to do? The line "We can remove only one element in the process." isn't clear either.

Comment: I have added original description

Comment: I recommend adding test cases for sequences of length 0, 1, 2, and 3. The first two are common special cases for problems like these, and the latter two are special cased in your implementation.

Comment: @cbojar Thanks. With that I found a bug.